# Mongoose update or create many values in one query

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a document like this:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("565e906bc2209d91c4357b59"),
    "userEmail" : "abc@example.com",
    "subscription" : {
        "project1" : {
            "subscribed" : false
        },
        "project2" : {
            "subscribed" : true
        },
        "project3" : {
            "subscribed" : false
        },
        "project4" : {
            "subscribed" : false
        }
    }
}
```

I'm using express to for my post web service call like this:

```
router.post('/subscribe', function(req, res, next) {
    MyModel.findOneAndUpdate(
        {
            userEmail: req.body.userEmail
        },
        {
            // stuck here on update query
        },
        {
            upsert: true
        }, function(err, raw) {
            if (err) return handleError(err);
            res.json({result: raw});
        }
    )
});
```

My `req` contains data like this:

```
{
    userEmail: "abc@example.com",
    subscription: ["project1", "project4"]
}
```

So these are the steps I would like to perform on this call:

1. Check user exists, otherwise create the user. For instance, if `abc@example.com` doesn't exist, create a new document with userEmail as `abc@example.com`.
2. If user exists, check `project1` and `project4` exists in `subscription` object. If not create those.
3. If `project1` and `project4` exists in `subscription`, then update the `subscribed` to `true`.

I'm not sure whether I can achieve all the above 3 steps with a single query. Kindly advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vimalraj,

You can accomplish this using [`$set`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/set/). The `$set` operator replaces the value of a field with the specified value. According to the docs:

> If the field does not exist, `$set` will add a new field with the specified value, provided that the new field does not violate a type constraint. If you specify a dotted path for a non-existent field, $set will create the embedded documents as needed to fulfill the dotted path to the field.

Since your `req.subscription` will be an array you'll have to build your query. to look like this:

```
{ 
  $set: { 
    "subscription.project1":{"subscribed" : true},
    "subscription.project4":{"subscribed" : true}
}
```

You can use [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to create an object from `req.subscription = ["project1","project4"] array`

```
var subscription= req.subscription.reduce(function(o,v){
  o["subscription." + v] = {subscription:true};
  return o;
},{});
```

Then your code becomes:

```
router.post('/subscribe', function(req, res, next) {

    var subscription= req.subscription.reduce(function(o,v){
      o["subscription." + v] = {subscription:true};
      return o;
    },{});

    MyModel.findOneAndUpdate(
        {
            userEmail: req.body.userEmail
        },
        {
             $set: subscription
        },
        {
            upsert: true
        }, function(err, raw) {
            if (err) return handleError(err);
            res.json({result: raw});
        }
    )
});
```

Comment: Great! Glad I could help!